# amforms - Specific entry in the notification template

Tags: plugin-amforms

How can I get a specific value from the submitted form? E.g. the fullName field.

The default template loops through all the fields with a switch but I just want to output one specific field. Can't get it to work.

Comment: You could make your own template and in the backend from the plugin you can set this template. Also not all fieldtypes are supported on the default template . Maybe you can give more details about what you already tried

Comment: I asked that Question once in the github issues: https://github.com/am-impact/amforms/issues/133

Comment: @DannyKlaren would you mind adding what worked for you as an official answer? Might help someone in the future with the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of a specific field by using

```
{{ submission.fieldHandle }}
```

E.g.

```
{{ submission.fullName }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have never used the plugin before, but according to their [documentation](https://github.com/am-impact/amforms#simple-field-tag), it should just be:

```
{% set form = craft.amForms.getForm('yourFormHandle') %}

{{ form.displayField('fullName') }}
```

Comment: That displays an input field with a label on the frontend, I have to target the fields in the notification template which will be sent via mail.